# How to completely disable the JMX interface for java applications

Tags: java, jvm, rmi, jmx, jconsole

Is there a (JVM-vendor agnostic) way to disable the JMX / RMI interface so no one can access it via jConsole or other tools?

If not, is there a way to restrict the access (also JVM-vendor agnostic).

I can limit the tcp connections to zero with `-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.maxConnectionThreads=0`. But this is probably not a good idea since it is discouraged to use.

Comment: @Community I disagree completely. The question is perfectly clear. What could anyone possibly not understand about 'disable the JMX / RMI interface'?

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that it is discouraged to use that system property (it isn't), but setting it to zero will disable RMI completely, not just JMX, which is probably not your intention. According to [this JMX page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html), remote JMX is not enabled by default: you have to set `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port`. So if you don't, the only host that can talk JMX to your JVM is the localhost. Or you could use one of the various authentication options to make it impossible for anybody to connect to JMX.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Thats interesting. So it seems that it is always active for local connections. We were considering possible misuse and exploitation of the those informations that are provided via JMX. 

I guess that is nothing to worry about?

Thank you for the hint about local / remote connections

Comment: Starting the JMX Agent when the application is already running is done via the Attach API, which can be disabled via `-XX:+DisableAttachMechanism`. This does not prevent JMX if you start it via command line options explicitly (in other words, before the application) and still allows your application to use JMX itself.